# Нужно объяснить маленькую часть кода

Tags: javascript

Есть спрайтовая анимация

```js
(function(x, y, el, t) {
  setInterval(function() {;
    (y > 1) ? (y = 0, (x = (x > 1) ? 0 : x + 1)) : (y += 1);
    el.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + x + "00% -" + y + "00%";
  }, 100);
})(
  0,
  0,
  document.getElementById("cat"),
);
```

```css
#cat {
  width: 112px;
  height: 156px;
  background-image: url(https://inter-net.pro/images/css/sprite-marsch.png);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cat"></div>
```

Кто может помочь объяснить javascript код? И желательно упростить код.

Comment: Само вызывающаяся лямбда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим все по порядку

Здесь объявляется само вызывающаяся лямбда

```
(function(x,y,el,t) {
```

---

Тоже лямбда вызывающаяся с определенным интервалом

```
setInterval(function() {
```

---

Тут тернарный оператор

```
;(y>1)?(y=0,(x=(x>1)?0:x+1)):(y+=1);
```

на простой `if` можно　перевести как

```
if ( y > 1 ) 
{
   y = 0;
   if (x > 1)
   {
     x = 0
   }
   else 
   {
     x += 1;
   }
} 
else
{
  y += 1;
}
```

---

Тут я думаю объяснять не нужно, идет присвоение стилей.

```
el.style.backgroundPosition = "-"+x+"00% -"+y+"00%";
```

---

Тоже не должно быть вопросов, задается интервал в 100мс.

```
}, 100);
```

---

Закрывается лямбда, и само-вызывается, в нее передаются аргументы `x = 0, y = 0, el = document.getElementById("cat")`

```
})(
  0,
  0,
  document.getElementById("cat"),
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
   (function(x,y,el,t) {
      setInterval(function() { // Обычный вызов функции с интервалом указанным вторым параметром
        ;(y>1)?(y=0,(x=(x>1)?0:x+1)):(y+=1); // зачем тут нужна ; не знаю, так обычно делают для модулей, тут она не нужна, все остальное это тернарные операции (короткий вариант if() {} else {} в виде - <условие> ? <значение, если условие выполнилось> : <значение, если условие не выполнилось>")
        el.style.backgroundPosition = "-"+x+"00% -"+y+"00%"; // простое задание стилей
      }, 100); // интервал вызова в миллисекундах
    })(0, 0, document.getElementById("cat")); // Эти аргументы передаются в функцию которая тут же вызывается (IIFE), соответственно x = 0, y = 0, el = document.getElementById("cat")
```

Упрощенный в моем понимании вариант:

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var el = document.getElementById("cat");
var func = function( x, y , el ) {
  setInterval(function() {
    if(y > 1) {
      y = 0;

      if(x > 1) {
        x = 0
      } else {
        x = x + 1;
      }
    } else {
      y = y + 1;
    }

    var XPercentagePosition = -x * 100 + '%';
    var YPercentagePosition = -x * 100 + '%';

    el.style.backgroundPosition = XPercentagePosition + ' ' + XPercentagePosition;
  }, 100);
}

func(x, y, el);
```

```css
#cat {
  width:112px;
  height:156px;
  background-image:url(https://inter-net.pro/images/css/sprite-marsch.png);
  background-position:0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cat"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за понятный ответ)